# Pathing Analysis web data

Tags: sql-server-2008, web-analytics, path-finding

I am doing some analysis on my raw web analytics data and trying to find common arrival paths on my web site leading up to a purchase. I have migrated all my data in to one tidy table / script below:

1. [ORDER_ID]: Non unique VARCHAR (A1000, A1001 etc)
2. [VISIT_IN_PATH]: Numeric (1,2,3,4,5 etc)
3. [VISIT_REMAINING]: Numeric (1,2,3,4,5 etc)
4. [CHANNEL]: VARCHAR (DIRECT / EMAIL / DISPLAY / PAID SEARCH / FREE SEARCH)

What I am hoping to get is a count of the paths so for example using just ORDER_ID ABC123 I might get the following:

COUNT/VISIT_IN_PATH_1/VISIT_IN_PATH_2/VISIT_IN_PATH_3/VISIT_IN_PATH_4/VISIT_IN_PATH_5
1/FREE SEARCH/FREE SEARCH/DIRECT/FREE SEARCH/DIRECT

I am pretty new to SQL and my first thought would be some kind of pivot, but every way I approach this I keep coming up against a wall where each possibility must be defined.

Surely there is a better easier way?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DummyPaths](
                                    [ORDER_ID] [varchar](64) NULL,
                                    [VISIT_IN_PATH] [bigint] NULL,
                                    [VISIT_REMAINING] [bigint] NULL,
                                    [MARKETING_CHANNEL] [varchar](256) NULL
                                )
GO

INSERT INTO DummyPaths (ORDER_ID,VISIT_IN_PATH,VISIT_REMAINING,MARKETING_CHANNEL)
VALUES      ('ABC123','1','5','FREE SEARCH'),
            ('ABC123','2','4','FREE SEARCH'),
            ('ABC123','3','3','DIRECT'),
            ('ABC123','4','2','FREE SEARCH'),
            ('ABC123','5','1','DIRECT'),
            ('ABC124','1','5','OTHER REFERRAL'),
            ('ABC124','2','4','OTHER REFERRAL'),
            ('ABC124','3','3','OTHER REFERRAL'),
            ('ABC124','4','2','OTHER REFERRAL'),
            ('ABC124','5','1','OTHER REFERRAL'),
            ('ABC125','1','5','DIRECT'),
            ('ABC125','2','4','AFFILIATE'),
            ('ABC125','3','3','AFFILIATE'),
            ('ABC125','4','2','AFFILIATE'),
            ('ABC125','5','1','AFFILIATE'),
            ('ABC126','1','5','EMAIL'),
            ('ABC126','2','4','EMAIL'),
            ('ABC126','3','3','DIRECT'),
            ('ABC126','4','2','DIRECT'),
            ('ABC126','5','1','DIRECT'),
            ('ABC127','1','5','FREE SEARCH'),
            ('ABC127','2','4','DIRECT'),
            ('ABC127','3','3','DIRECT'),
            ('ABC127','4','2','FREE SEARCH'),
            ('ABC127','5','1','DIRECT'),
            ('ABC128','1','5','DIRECT'),
            ('ABC128','2','4','EMAIL'),
            ('ABC128','3','3','EMAIL'),
            ('ABC128','4','2','EMAIL'),
            ('ABC128','5','1','DIRECT'),
            ('ABC129','1','5','FREE SEARCH'),
            ('ABC129','2','4','FREE SEARCH'),
            ('ABC129','3','3','FREE SEARCH'),
            ('ABC129','4','2','FREE SEARCH'),
            ('ABC129','5','1','DIRECT')
```

I would be very grateful for any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have been playing with this and found that the following works:

```
with        dataset
as
(
select  ORDER_ID
        ,[1] as 'VISIT1'
        ,[2] as 'VISIT2'
        ,[3] as 'VISIT3'
        ,[4] as 'VISIT4'
        ,[5] as 'VISIT5'                
from 
(
  select order_id, visit_in_path, MARKETING_CHANNEL
  from dummypaths
) x
pivot
(
  min(MARKETING_CHANNEL)
  for visit_in_path in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
) p
) 


select      x.VISIT1
            ,x.VISIT2
            ,x.VISIT3
            ,x.VISIT4
            ,x.VISIT5
            ,MAX(dupes) as 'count'
from
(
select      
            VISIT1
            ,VISIT2
            ,VISIT3
            ,VISIT4
            ,VISIT5
            ,ROW_NUMBER() over 
                            (partition by    VISIT1
                                            ,VISIT2
                                            ,VISIT3
                                            ,VISIT4
                                            ,VISIT5
                            order by        VISIT1 asc
                            ) as 'dupes'
from dataset
) x
group by    x.VISIT1
            ,x.VISIT2
            ,x.VISIT3
            ,x.VISIT4
            ,x.VISIT5
```